# Kibana Dashboard: Pipe the output of a query to another

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Version: Elasticsearch 7.1

Hello.
I make a query that returns some user_ids. I'd like to then make another query, using the user_ids as an input, and render a dashboard from this "pipeline".

I'm new to ES and I'm not sure I can do that. Could you kindly provide some hint?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, one cannot achieve nested queries like in SQL in Elasticsearch (remember, it'sa NoSQL). There is something called application-side joins in Elasticsearch. Check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html). It might be useful for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I've already seen it but it's application-side, so unsupported by Kibana dashboards, looks like. I'll look into Painless to see if something can be achieved.